# Laravel: Get 405 Method Not Allowed while posting data using jquery ajax api to store data

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to save data to a database using jQuery ajax api in Laravel 4.* and receive a 405 error.

**View**

```
{{Form::open(array("","id"=>"frmProcessLevel"))}}
   <input name="{{$result->id.'_'.str_replace(' ','-',$title)}}" id="processLevel">

   <h3>{{$title}} Impact rating</h3>
   <table class="table table-bordered" style="font-size: 12px">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>Level</th>
               <th>Category</th>
               <th>Description</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody class="selectable selectable-rows">
           @foreach($impact_rating as $key => $value)
                <tr data-key="{{$key}}">
                    <td>{{$key}}</td>
                    <td>{{$impact_cat[$key]}}</td>
                    <td>{{$value}}</td>
                </tr>
           @endforeach
       </tbody>
   </table>
   {{Form::token()}}
   {{Form::submit('Save')}}
{{Form::close()}}

<script>
        //Submit the form functions
        $("#frmProcessLevel").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var selectedLevel = $("#processLevel").val();
            var datastring = 'selectedLevel='+selectedLevel;
            //alert(selectedLevel);
            $.ajax({ 
            headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: "/bia/create_critical_process/",
                type: "post",
                data: datastring,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }, "json");
        });
</script>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::post('/bia/create_critical_process',array('before' => 'csrf','uses'=>'BiaController@createBiaStepThree'));
```

**Controller**

```
 public function createBiaStepThree(){
        $data = Input::all();
        $last_insert_bia_id = Session::get('last_insert_bia_id');
        if (Request::ajex())
        {
            Log::info(Input::all());
            $bia = new CriticalProcessStepThree();
            $bia->impact_rating_clinical = $data['selectedLevel'];
            $bia->key_process_fk = 1;
            $bia->bia_entry_fk = $last_insert_bia_id;
            $bia->save();
        }
    }
```

Passing token: http://words.weareloring.com/development/laravel/laravel-4-csrf-tokens-when-using-jquerys-ajax/

Comment: Your route looks wrong to me. Your missing the key from the array for the controller it uses. Should be `'uses'=>'BiaController@createBiaStepThree'`

Comment: @Jeemusu I already added that, still not working

Comment: Then update your question to reflect the new code. By still not working I assume your getting the same 405 error?

Comment: @Jeemusu yes getting same error, I updated code.

Comment: Ok based on what i understood, I changed route to /bia/create_critical_process? and had 404 instead 405

Comment: Could it be a server problem? I just cut down all your code and put it into a clean laravel install. Worked without a problem.  Can you post the form normally (without ajax)? Also you spelt Ajax wrong in your controller method `Request::ajax()`.

Comment: Try `Route::post('bia/create_critical_process'...` (remove the beginning slash).

Comment: Try php composer.phar dump-autoload

Comment: Check the output of `artisan routes`

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you have a typo.

It should be

```
if(Request::ajax())
```

instead of

```
Request::ajex()
```

Not sure if this is your only problem, but that is one of them.

EDIT : also you should set your request type.

```
type    :"POST",
```

Also make sure your route is setup to accept post requests like.

```
Route::post('route/what/ever/you/want', 'Controller@function');
```

Answer (score 0):

Example in AJAX.

```
var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("password", password.val());
        $.ajax({
             url: 'btn',
             method: 'post',
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             cache: false,
             dataType: 'json',
             data: formData,
             success: function(data){
                    var vote_now = $("#vote_now");
                    if(data.btn == 'visible'){
                        vote_now.fadeIn();

                    }
                    else {

                        vote_now.fadeOut();
                    }

                    },
                error: function(){

             }
        });
```